# VSCode how to set cmd + click short cut

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I set the shortcut for `cmd + F12` to `cmd+left click` in the shortcut settings in VSCode?
When I double click the `Keybinding` it asks for the shortcut input, but it doesn't register a click as an input.

[image]